# On-demand resources (ODR) get completed/total file size of downloaded tag

Tags: ios, swift, resources, progress, on-demand-resources

I'm downloading zip archives via ODR and want to show a progress and the completed/total file size to the user (like "3/10MB downloaded")
Using KVO I managed to observe the *fractionCompleted* property of the associated **Progress** object, so I'm able to show a progress bar.

The code looks like that:

```
let request = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [tag])

request.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted, options: [.new, .old]) { [weak self] _, change in
      guard let progress = change.newValue else { return }

      // Use new progress value here
}
```

Now, to show the completed/total file size in bytes I tried to access *completedUnitCount* and *totalUnitCount*, which happens to always have the values 1 (meaning 1 file?).

How can I obtain the correct values of *completedUnitCount* and *totalUnitCount*?

Answer (score -1):

That was surprise for me as well.
We've managed to solve this by using the fractionCompleted property of the Progress value:

progress.fractionCompleted